# Facebook App Invite Dialog is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Facebook App Invite Dialog in my iOS app.
For test purposes I created [this](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/redirectToContent?id=422255598) test application and generated App Link for it.

Running next code:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/1453356328318807"];
//optionally set previewImageURL
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someimage-1200x628.jpg"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:self];
```

shows app invite dialog with ability to chose friends and send them invites to my app. Everything goes fine, I got invocation of delegate method:

```
(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
```

with result:

```
{
    didComplete = 1;
}
```

But receiver didn't get notification. Receiver user is also registered user for my app Tester User with native Facebook App installed.

Maybe somebody got same problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: I have exactly same issue. Possibly a bug.

Comment: can i get all user information who invited...like email

Comment: "App Invites will no longer be supported" https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/
for anyone found here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine and this feature will actual work when you publish your app because some Facebook integration require approval before usage. Submit your app for approval in Status And Review section

Comment: Can we get extra confirmation about this? I'm doing the same thing and the App invite's never actually sent to the inbox of the receiving user.

Answer (score 3):

Did the test user already installed the app? If so, it's expected that they don't receive App Invite notifications.

You can read more in the documentation on [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview):

> If the person already has the app installed, they will not receive a
>   push notification.

Can you check if this might be the situation?

Comment: Thanks, but test user doesn't have app installed. I've read documentation.

Comment: Are you sure? Have they accepted the App permissions in last month? I've checked your app settings and it seems that the one test user you have actually accepted/installed the app before.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I got something wrong. If test user accepted/installed app, then removed it. Is this feature going to work?

Comment: No, probably not. I think there is a period of (about) 30 days where it's still considered as being "installed", because it was recently done so.

Can you test with a new test user that -has not accepted- the app yet? So a fresh start?

Comment: Have you check it yet?If you have installed the app in 30 days, it will not receive the IOS push notification,but only receive the notification in facebook app?

Answer (score -1):

My app invites didn't trigger a notification because the app was not public. Ajay_nasa suggested publishing the app. I handled it by adding testers and developers to the app in the roles section of the app dashboard (i.e. https://developers.facebook.com/apps//roles/). After that, those user received the invites successfully.

Comment: If you followed another answer, please add a comment to that answer rather then your own answer

Comment: I tried to comment but I received an error that I needed "50 reputation" to comment.